# Python Multiprocessing Pool Worker Processes Failing to Terminate

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, jupyter-notebook, python-multiprocessing

I'm using Python's multiprocesssing.Pool.map() to execute a function over a bunch of data in Jupyter notebook. I am getting correct and expected results from the pool, however the worker processes refuses to terminate even after I do a Pool.close(), Pool.join() and Pool.terminate() and I just can't figure out why.

The following is a code snippet where I create the pool and call the map() function on my data:

```
   for i in xrange(num_batches):
        lw_range = int(i * self.batch_size)
        up_range = int((i + 1) * self.batch_size)

        # Put the remainder into the last batch
        if remainder_size > 0 and i == (self.num_proc - 1):
            up_range += int(remainder_size)

        subset_df = self.tr_df[lw_range:up_range]
        arg_list.append((subset_df, self.dates_v, self.sec_list, self.dict_mode, universe_m, speaker_type, section,  \
                         corprep_type, aggregation))

    sub_sent_matrices = mp_pool.map(_gen_sentiments_worker, arg_list)

    print "Multiprocessing pool completed!...",

    mp_pool.close()
    mp_pool.join()
    mp_pool.terminate()
```

The following is the function I'm calling in parallel with map(). Basically it instantiates an object which parses some text and returns the results as a numpy array/matrix:

```
def _gen_sentiments_worker((tr_df, dates_v, sec_list, dict_mode, 
     universe_m, speaker_type, section, corprep_type, aggregation)):

     tr_nlp_instance = TranscriptNLP(tr_df, dates_v, sec_list, 
     dict_mode=dict_mode)

     sub_sent_m = tr_nlp_instance.gen_sentiments_matrix(universe_m, 
     section, speaker_type, corprep_type, aggregation)

     return sub_sent_m
```

I'm not sure if this is due to some mishandling of multiprocessing.Pool() or some weird conflict with Jupyter notebook. Has anyone encountered and successfully worked around such an issue before?

Thanks!